# ¿Cómo contar las conexiones activas que tiene Apache?

Tags: apache

¿Cómo puedo saber cuántas son las conexiones que tiene activas Apache en un servidor Windows?, ¿Hay alguna forma de saberlo? He intentado con el netstat pero no me da, agradecería mucho una ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

utiliza el comando `netstat -anb` encontrarás que te muestra todos los procesos del sistema, busca en especifico el `httpd.exe`este es el servicio Apache, te mostrará cuantas conexiones activas tienes con el estado `LISTENING`.

Comment: Hola iuninefrendor, gracias por tu respuesta, ya encontré como hacerlo con el mismo apache configurando un módulo que se llama mod_status, igual también probare con el netstat a ver cómo va esa.